# Which CMS supports ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I am to develop a website for a IT company, I want to use ASP.NET MVC 3 to develop it I also  want to use a CMS with it so that it is easy to change the content of the site, without having to go into the codes.

I want to use MVC 3 for this.

Can anyone help me in deciding which CMS should I go for ?

My requirement is to create a website for an IT company using ASP.NET MVC 3, and use a CMS with it so that content management becomes easy.

Any ideas / help / links / will be appreciated.

Update : Now Wordpress is also available with .NET

Warm Regards

Comment: Orchard CMS - http://www.orchardproject.net/

Comment: @tawman - Orchard does not plug into an MVC site.  Orchard is its own site, that allows MVC extensions, which is not what the poster was asking for.

Comment: @MystereMan Agreed, and hence I suggest he reverse the approach. Pick the CMS that can be extended to meet the additional requirements.

Comment: Umbraco ? Does Umbraco support MVC ?

Comment: Yes and no, it depends on your definition.  Be very careful with the term "CMS" as it has many different definitions, and also be very careful about what you mean by "integrate" or "embed".  You will find a lot of people will say things with those terms but only mean a very specific kind of integration.

Comment: By CMS, I ONLY want the adding content to be like CMS like ( like the one that Wordpress has). I dont want to go into code for that. Does Umbraco has that ?

Comment: You can look into http://compositec1.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "plug-in" CMS that you can use in MVC.  You would have to write it yourself.

There are, however, a number of CMS's that allow you to extend them via MVC.  Orchard, for example is a popular one.

There is a big difference between an MVC site that has a CMS and a CMS that allows you to extend it with MVC.  You should understand this distinction, and decide which way you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a solution like N2 CMS. It's an API that allows you to create a CMS programmatically.

http://n2cms.codeplex.com/

Comment: hey thanks, I will definitely try this..

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [MVC Easy CMS](http://mvceasycms.ism-ukraine.com/). It can be installed as NuGet package to the existing MVC 3.0 project.

Answer (score 0):

You can plug Umbraco v5 into an existing MVC site or an existing MVC site into Umbraco v5. Umbraco v5 is a complete rewrite currently based on MVC3.

Comment: seems a little confusing... can you tell in more detail or guide me to a link

Comment: The problem here is one of definitions.  I'm not familiar with Umbraco, but my guess is that you can place Umbraco routes within an MVC site, but that those "pages" are entirely Umbraco controlled.  This is different from, say, embedding CMS content within a page of your MVC site.

Comment: Umbraco is based on ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Paolo - so is Orchard, but that doesn't mean you can just plug CMS content into an existing page of your site.  These are complex systems, and the way you integrate with them is very different.

Answer (score 0):

The open source [DD4T project](http://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/) (Dynamic Delivery For Tridion) provides an MVC.NET front-end to [SDL Tridion WCM](http://www.sdl.com/en/wcm/)-managed content.

Tridion is however quite expensive, so I'm not sure I should be even mentioning it...